# Javascript form.submit() works only when debugging

Tags: javascript

I have a weird problem when I try to submit a form. My page contains a html table and one column has a link that deletes the line from the DB calling a js function.

The html/php line is the following one:

```
<input type="hidden" name="deleteid" value=0>
print ", <a href=\"\" class=\"action_link\" onClick=\"javascript:delete_line($id);\">delete</a>";
```

The javascript function is the following one:

```
function delete_line(team_id) {
  if (confirm('<?php echo $txt_confirm_del_team;?>')){
    document.formName.elements.deleteid.value = team_id;
    document.formName.submit();
  }
}
```

If I put a breakpoint on the line "document.formName.submit();", the called page can read the parameter "deletedid". If not, the parameters are not passed to the page called by the submit.
Btw, I have another issue if I use `getElementById()` to retrieve the element or the form in the javascript function: it says the `getelementbyid` is null (and it's not because I can retreive it using the syntax `document.formName.elements.deleteid`)

thanks

Comment: Why does the link point back to the current page? Why are you using a link for this in the first place? Use a form!

Comment: The `<a>` "onclick" calls "delete_line" but that function is called "delete_equipe" ...

Comment: If you have a problem with some JavaScript/HTML then show people the JavaScript/HTML and not some PHP which generates it (given some data we can't see).

Comment: I have some problem formatting my question...

Comment: `.submit()` is jQuery. You have it included?

Comment: If I put a breakpoint on the line "document.formName.submit();" the parameter is passed to the called page. And the debug doesn't show any error.

Comment: @Bondye — While jQuery has a submit method, the one being used in the question is [DOM level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-76767676).

Comment: Btw...I didn't write this application, I'm just trying to fix the bug. So I don't know why the former developer (that left the company) created this page on this way.

Comment: @Pointy -- Sorry, a typo while writing the question

Comment: Have you tried validating the HTML? You may be experiencing problems due to two elements sharing the same ID, for example.

Comment: @squeamish ossifrage — the element "deleteid" is unique in the page

Comment: getElementById would return null because the element doesn't have an `id` it has a name so you could try getElementsByName (notice elements as in plural). As other people have noted; it would be helpful if you'd post some html. Do you have multiple hidden input boxes with multiple links? Then could you post a couple of them?

Comment: @HMR You are right...I didn't read properly the code and I missed that the id wasn't defined. But I have still the main problem that it works only when debugging with a breakpoint. Also, it's the only hidden textbox in the page

Answer (score 0):

There may be some other event handlers there, you can open the page in Chrome and right click the anchor, then choose "inspect element" and then check out the event handlers in the "event listeners" tab.

As far as the code you posted; there is nothing wrong with it. The following works just fine for me:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
 <a onclick="javascript:delete_line(22);">delete</a>
    <script>
function delete_line(nr){
  console.log(nr);
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```